# Javascript Runtime error in ASPX page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I got strange error when i run the .apsx page

Error is below:

"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'addEventListener': object is null or undefined"

I could not understand, why this error occur. How can i fix it plz help !

Comment: Maybe you want to show the code of the ASPX page causing this? Or you don't judge it necessary?

Comment: post your code, please.  Also, if you are using a custom third party ASP.NET control, post its version and browser version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE, than perhaps it's because for IE<9, you need to use attachEvent.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: I am using IE 9. Can i use attachEvent ?if yes, then how i use AttachEvent ?

Comment: I don't think you read/understand the answer...  anyway, if you are using IE9, the addEventListener should work for you.  must be something else.